# How do I create formatted javascript console log messages

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webkit, exploit

I 'waddled' by the Console in Chrome on Facebook today. 
Surprisingly I got this message in the console. 
[image]
Now my question is:
How is this possible?
I know that there are a few 'exploit' methods for the console, but how can you make such font formatting in the console? (and is it console.log?)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Yes, you can format the `console.log()` with something like this:

```
console.log("%cExtra Large Yellow Text with Red Background", "background: red; color: yellow; font-size: x-large");
```

Note the `%c` preceding the text in the first argument and the style specifications in the second argument. The text will look like your example.

See [Google's "Styling Console Output with CSS"](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css) or [FireBug's Console Documentation](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.log) for more details.

The documentation links also include some other neat tricks like including object links in a console log as well.

Comment: You might want to check that a compatible browser is in use before trying to use format strings in `console.log`, since older browsers might stop your script with an exception.  [caniuse says](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_console_log_substitution_strings) it was introduced in Firefox 9 and Edge 79; Chrome started supporting it evidently some time before Chrome 83 but we don't know exactly when.

Answer (score 44):

Try this:

```
console.log("%cThis will be formatted with blue text", "color: blue");
```

Quoting the docs,

> You use the %c format specifier to apply custom CSS rules to any
>   string you write to the Console with console.log() or related
>   methods.

Source:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css

Comment: Hi downvoter, any comments to add?  - it's hard to improve an answer (that you think is not good) when you don't leave comments explaining yourself. :)

Answer (score 37):

You can also format substrings.

```
var red = 'color:red';
var blue = 'color:blue';
console.log('%cHello %cWorld %cfoo %cbar', red, blue, red, blue);
```

[image]

Comment: Note that it is only possible to style within the first argument of `console.log` and the styles must follow immediately.

Answer (score 10):

From Google's website: [site](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write#styling_console_output_with_css)

```
console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");
```

Answer (score 3):

Just extending other answers and you can reuse the existing css style of selector, class, element. Try this in SO console window.

```
const customLog = (message, cssSelector) =>
  console.log(
    `%c${message}`,
    Object.entries(getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(cssSelector)))
      .map(([k, v]) => `${k}:${v}`)
      .join(";")
  );

customLog("Hello StackOverflow", "#question-header > div > a");

customLog("Hello StackOverflow", "strong");

customLog("Hello StackOverflow", "a");
```

[image]